# MouseWheelListener doesn't work - Java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to catch mouse wheel event with no success. This is my main class:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        Panel pan = new Panel();
        add(pan);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main wnd = new Main(); 

        wnd.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        wnd.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        wnd.pack();
        wnd.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

and this is JPanel class which implements the mouse wheel listener:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements MouseWheelListener {

    public Panel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        System.out.println("scrolled");

    }

}
```

When the JFrame opens, there is no event when I roll my mouse wheel. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you register the Panel as a MouseMotionListener?

Comment: I don't see where you've added any kind of listener to anything. Have you gone through the appropriate tutorials?

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at [How to use Mouse Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: class Panel extends JPanel implements MouseWheelListener

Comment: Look at the tutorial. The implements will do nothing if you don't add the wheel listener to an appropriate component.

Comment: You've got the wires, but you've neglected to connect them -- so no circuit will be achieved until you do.

Comment: addMouseWheelListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

Ok,thanks to the comments I solved it. I added this line:

```
addMouseWheelListener(this);
```

In the Panel's constructor.